# Saving NSAttributedString to Parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, nsattributedstring

Parse doesn't support direct saving of `NSAttributedStrings`. Converting to HTML isn't the most straightforward. Anyone have a friendly method for storing `NSAttributedStrings` (font & superscript) to Parse.com?

Comment: outstanding question...

Comment: `NSAttributedString` is a `NSString` with a `NSDictionary`, where key are `NSRange` (with NSValue) and values are attributes. You could strip it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, decided to go with saving an rtf string onto Parse, based off @Wain's comment.

```
// convert NSAttributedString to RTFString and save to Parse
PFObject *note = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Note"];     
NSAttributedString *noteAttributedText = self.noteTextView.attributedText;
NSDictionary *documentAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:NSRTFTextDocumentType,NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute, nil];
NSData *rtfData = [noteAttributedText dataFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, noteAttributedText.length) documentAttributes:documentAttributes error:NULL];
NSString *rtfString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:rtfData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
note[@"noteTextAsRTFString"] = rtfString;

// convert RTFString to NSAttributedString after pulling from Parse
NSString *rtfString = [pfObject objectForKey:@"noteTextAsRTFString"];
NSData *data = [rtfString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSAttributedString *noteAttributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:data options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSRTFTextDocumentType} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
```